# Internal website over SSL VPN (F5 Network) session issue

Tags: networking, ssl, vpn, f5-big-ip

We have F5 Networks SSL VPN setup and added some internal websites in F5 portal.
One website works good, but the other one has session problem.

When I sign in to F5 portal, from there I go to internal website (which F5 redirects)
[image: [see the image here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUZSy.png), then I can sign in into that website with X user, but then when I want to sign in with other user, it stills signs me in with X user not matter what user you write.
Even if you write random words (djqwejw - 321) it still opens X users profile, it's like session is stuck and can't be signed out.

What can be the problem? The internal website works well, but that website from F5 Networks SSL VPN has that session problem.

Comment: So you log in via the F5 portal as user X, but you want to access the website as user Y?

Answer (score 0):

The F5 portal displays applications associated to access profiles.

Assuming you have access to the F5 device, you can find the list of applications enabled in the F5 portal at Access > Connectivity/VPN > Portal Access, and you can click on the corresponding access profile which is defined under Access > Profiles/Policies > Access Profiles.

You can configure an access profile by setting parameters like SSO (single sign on) configuration (which you can disable if needed), logout URI and timeouts.